# WCF WebService on Android project - How to get byte[] type via SoapObjects?

Tags: java, android, wcf, byte, android-ksoap2

I have Android / Java project with Network threads. It is connected to WCF WebService which provides me method GetAddonsTypes.

GetAddonsTypes return long, int, and string items so I use own Parser (String / regex) which also create object in myDataSource (it's SQLite database). Now I have problem with my second method which is called GetProducts. GetProducts return long, int and Image.

I Would like to store Image as byte[] type. But how I can deal with binary files with SoapObjects? Maybe I should cast this anyType{} to binary file, but how I can do it?

This is how looks SoapObject result from  GetProducts (.toString())

> anyType{DocumentElement=anyType{Tabela=anyType{ID=701; lg=1;
>   ProductImage=anyType{}; };

## My Network Thread

```
Thread networkThread1 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          try {
             final String METHOD_NAME = "GetAddonsTypes";
             final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetAddonsTypes";
             SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);         
             SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
             envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
             envelope.dotNet = true;
             HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
             ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
             final SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();


             runOnUiThread (new Runnable(){ 
                 public void run() {
                     ParseTable(result.getProperty(1).toString());
                    }
                });
            }
         catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("WS", e.toString());
         }
        }
      };

       public void ParseTable(String input)
    {
        myDataSource myDatasource;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(PID=)(\\d*); (flg=)(\\d*); (Name=)(\\w*);");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        myDatasource = new myDatasource(this);
        myDatasource.open();
        while (m.find()) {
            try {
                myDatasource.createMyItem(Long.parseLong(m.group(2)),  Integer.parseInt(m.group(4)), m.group(6));
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Parser Error", e.toString());
            }
        }
        myDatasource.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

" In the getProperty method I'm using the following:

Info.type = MarshalBase64.BYTE_ARRAY_CLASS
"

From this  post: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Getting-Image-Over-Using-Web-Service-and-Ksoap2/td-p/491835

Comment: AnyType{} is null value. That's why it won't work. But I use some part of implementation from your link so thanks!